# gevent breaks requests/urllib2 timeouts

Tags: python, urllib2, gevent, eventlet

Some time ago I wrote code that interacts with foreign service for my Django project:

```
    try:
        response = requests.get('some host', timeout=TIMEOUT)
    except:
        log.warning('timeout')
        return None
```

I tested it in my devel envierment (`python manage.py runserver`) and timeouts work fine. Then I decide to patch it with **gevent** by specifying pool implementation for **gunicorn**, like so:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -k gevent
```

And now `get` call is not interrupted by timout exception. I changed pool implementation to **eventlet** and it works as expected:

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn -k eventlet
```

Is there any way to fix **gevent**?

Comment: try to update gevent to its github version.  `socket.setdefaulttimeout(TIMEOUT)` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/69). This bug is fixed in version **1.0dev**, you can install it from github:

```
pip install cython
pip install git+https://github.com/surfly/gevent.git
```

@j-f-sebastian, thank you for hint!